# How to change the expiration time of Google access token?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, jwt, access-token

I'm trying to get Google Cloud access token using JAVA with the following code(ignoring some unnecessary settings):

```
GoogleCredentials sourceCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountStream);
DownscopedCredentials downscopedCredentials = DownscopedCredentials.newBuilder()
                .setSourceCredential(sourceCredentials)
                .setCredentialAccessBoundary(credentialAccessBoundary)
                .build();
AccessToken accessToken = downscopedCredentials.refreshAccessToken();
```

and the expiration time of the returned token is 3599 (1 hour) by default, I'm trying to change it to 300.

So I add `.createWithCustomLifetime(3000)` as follows:

```
GoogleCredentials sourceCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountStream)
                .createWithCustomLifetime(3000);
```

Now I know that it's using JWT to get a new token.

After setting the `createWithCustomLifetime(300)`, the `'exp'` field of JWT payload is actually changed like this:

```
{
    "iat": $time_stamp,
    "exp": $time_stamp + 300
}
```

But the response data is still the same like this:

```
{
    "access_token": $token_response,
    "expires_in": 3599
}
```

That is to say, the expiration time is still 3599 instead of 300._

I wonder if I can do anything to make the `token_response` `expires_in` 300?

Thanks for any tips.